# Table with a description section

Tags: tables, packages, description, line, xltabular

Am having some problems with xltabular package when trying to draw this table, the problem when I try to make other tables the result will be like the first one, but when I delete the package from my main tex the table becomes complete. So can I do it without using this package?
The code for the first table

```
{

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ l | X }
  \caption{Data description  of dependent \& independent variables.}
 \label{table: vardescription}\\
 \hline \hline

\textbf{\normalsize Variable} & \textbf{\normalsize Description}  \\
 \hline
\endfirsthead
 \hline \hline

\textbf{Excess  returns} & In this research, our main goal is in showing the directional predictability, where the \textbf{dependent variable} is the dummy sign return indicator.
\[ 
\mathit{Excess\ return} =
  \begin{cases}
    1,  \quad\text{if the excess returns is } >0\\
    0, \quad\text{if the excess returns is } < 0 
  \end{cases}
\]
\\ \hline

\textbf{Recession} &
The recession defined by the \textbf{NBER} are used.
\[ \mathit{Recession} =
  \begin{cases}
    1,  \quad\text{if the  economy is in a recession},\\
     0, \quad\text{if the economy  is in an expansion}
  \end{cases}
\]
\\ \hline

\textbf{Dividend to price} & Dividends from past year divided by closing value of index at month end.
      \\[0ex]\hline
\textbf{Earning to price} & Earnings over the past year divided by closing value of index at month end.
     \\[0ex]\hline
\textbf{Term spread} & The 10 year US Treasury Bill less 3 month US Treasury Bill. \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}
}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{This is the heading}
\caption*{\footnotesize Smaller note of table that describes what the table is all about.}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
\toprule
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}   \\
                &     Base   &   Robust   &  Cluster   \\
\midrule
Size            &-0.000645   &-0.000645   &-0.000645   \\
                &  (-0.83)   &  (-0.83)   &  (-0.39)   \\
\midrule
Observations    &     5035   &     5035   &     5035   \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize * p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: This table with the package]
[image: The result for the second table]

Comment: The problem is not clear. Could you explain a bit more, and post a minimal code illustrating  what the problem is?

Comment: @Bernard, these are the codes for both tables, but the problem for the first table to be completed with the lines is to delete the xltabular package. But that ruins the second one, can I use another code to achieve the second one without using that package.

Comment: Please merge and extend your code fragments to complete but small document, which we can test as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works fine loading the relevant packages. I added some small improvements and code simplifications.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular, booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ l | >{\arraybackslash}X }
 \caption{Data description of dependent \& independent variables.}
 \label{table: vardescription}\\
 \hline \hline
%
\textbf{\normalsize Variable} & \textbf{\normalsize Description} \\
 \hline
\endfirsthead
 \hline \hline
%
\textbf{Excess returns} & In this research, our main goal is in showing the directional predictability, where the \textbf{dependent variable} is the dummy sign return indicator.
\[ \textit{Excess\ return} =
 \begin{cases*}
 1, & if the excess returns is $ >0 $,\\
 0, & if the excess returns is $ < 0 $. 
 \end{cases*} \]
\\ \hline
\textbf{Recession} &
The recession defined by the \textbf{NBER} are used.
\[ \textit{Recession} =
 \begin{cases*}
 1, & if the economy is in a recession,\\
 0, & if the economy is in an expansion.
 \end{cases*}\]
\\ \hline
\textbf{Dividend to price} & Dividends from past year divided by closing value of index at month end.
 \\[0ex]\hline
\textbf{Earning to price} & Earnings over the past year divided by closing value of index at month end.
 \\[0ex]\hline
\textbf{Term spread} & The 10 year US Treasury Bill less 3 month US Treasury Bill. \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the code, cause I was mistaken with the code for the first table if you tired it now will give you the result as it appears in the snapshots above.

Comment: Even with the modified code I have no problem. Check whether you've loaded the same packages as I do in my code. I had problems compile until I loaded `mathtools` (or `amsmath`).